# Search text in kickstart snippets via Red Hat Satellite

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, kickstart

Is it possible to search for particular text over all `Kickstart` snippets?
I'm using `Red Hat Satellite 5.4.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in RHN Satellite.

Problem solved by adding all `kickstart snippets` to new `kickstart profile` and searching via `kickstart file` of newly created `kickstart profile`.